# How to display usb pendrive contents in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to access the pendrive in android mobiles and need to read the contents inside pendrive. And to read and write inside pendrive functionality also required.

I have used few flutter plugins it were not detecting usb pen drives. I need to access the usb pendrive in mobile phones in android.